# disable types annotation in google-closure-compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

there has a [project](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) that it use webpack for developing while use google-closure-compiler for production. Everytime after developed, i must add types annotation even though it compiler correctly with webpack. So, can i disable the type checking or not use type annotation with google-closure-compiler?

Comment: In addition, i can't replace google-closure-compiler by webpack in production , because google-closure-compiler has some i18n code in project source code , webpack can't understand these

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jscomp_off` to turn off diagnostic groups. So to disable type checking, you say `--jscomp_off=checkTypes`. The diagnostic groups that can be turned on/off are defined [in this file](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/DiagnosticGroups.java).